# How does 話{はなし}が噛{か}み合{あ}わない work?

Tags: grammar, translation, words

I saw this phrase discussed on esaura.cc

> 話が噛み合わない
>   'There's a gap in their conversation.'
>   'They can't meet on common ground.'
>   'They have been at odds with each other.'
>   'They have not been on the same page.'

Is this the same `噛み` as in `[噛]{か}み[付]{つ}く` 'to bite (at), to snap at, to snarl at' or `噛{か}む` 'to bite, to chew, to gnaw'? If so, or if not so, would anyone care to explain or expand on the metaphoric implications of the original sentence (on the assumption that it uses a metaphor)?

Here is the original page: http://esaura.cc/questions/598

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A definition from [Jim Breen's EDICT](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%99%9B%E3%81%BF%E5%90%88%E3%81%86&eng=&dict=edict):

> 噛み合う かみあう
>   (v5u,vi) to gear (engage) with; to be in gear (mesh); to bite each other

Gears have teeth, so it could be said that they "bite" into each other.

[image: gears]

Comment: thank you! did you use an online dictionary to get that definition?

Comment: I find [Rikaichan](http://www.polarcloud.com/rikaichan/) (or [Rikaikun](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jipdnfibhldikgcjhfnomkfpcebammhp)) invaluable for this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you can see a relation with gears that have dents (aka teeth, 歯) and when two gears are well in phase, well united, the teeth are properly interleaved.  I think you can derive something like the "fitness of bites", i.e., 噛み合う from there.

It's quite far-fetched and purely hypothetical, but still, it make sense (to me at least).